# What is the correct term for "2" vs "two"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, orthography, numbers

When written this way, "2", what is the correct term?
When written this way, "two", what is the correct term?

Answer (score 7):

'2' is an ***Arabic numeral*** ([here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals)).

'Two' is a ***word***. You can also call it a ***number word***.

Answer (score 5):

When written as "2", it is a *numeral*.  When written as "two", you could refer to it as *spelled out*, *written out*, or possibly *longhand*.

Comment: Or, number names.

Comment: @NVZ: Both "2" and "two" are numerals, aka number names. They both represent a number, as does the Roman numeral "II".

Comment: This is a silly citation, but "two" is also a numeral. https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/numbers-numerals-digits.html

Comment: In context, "numeral" is quite clearly *"a conventional symbol that represents a number"* [*(Merriam-Webster)*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/numeral); no one's going to mistake "Write numbers below 10 as numerals" to mean anything but that you should use digits (what the Brits call "figures").

Answer (score 3):

The AP style guide refers to representations such as `2` or `10` as "*figures*," not "numerals," since "two" or "ten" is also a numeral:

> nu·mer·al  (no͞o′mər-əl, nyo͞o′-)
>
> n. A symbol or mark used to represent a number.

([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/numeral))

If you don't believe that, [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/numeral) calls words numerals explicitly:

> noun
>
> 1.
>   a word, letter, symbol, or figure, etc., expressing a number; number:

---

As for the words, AP Style just says "spell out."

I would suggest "*spelled out*" or "*written out*," but not "longhand," that refers to [cursive writing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/longhand).

**Tl;dr**:

`2` is a figure.

`two` is "spelled out."

Answer (score 1):

For "2":

- "2" is a [*digit*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digit),<sup>1</sup> as "as a digit;" if it were "42" it would "as digits"
- [*figure*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figure)<sup>2</sup> is also used for this, particularly in British English and older American English
- Merriam-Webster uses "as a number" or "as numbers" for this form in its definitions, such as for *figure* above

For "two":

- "as a word;" "forty-two" would be "as words"

*(While it's technically true that 2 is a word if you use it in a sentence, the phrase is unambiguous.)*

---

<sup>1</sup> *"any of the Arabic numerals 1 to 9 and usually the symbol 0"* - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digit)

<sup>2</sup> *"a symbol that represents a number"* - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figure)